# How to tell when number has passed a multiple of another number?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

Say I have a list of numbers:

```
foo = [random.randint(0, 9) for n in range(10)]
```

and I have a function

```
def bar(lst):
    total = 0
    for i in lst:
        total += i
        if total % 4 == 0:
            print "passed multiple of 4"

bar(foo)
```

How do I get the print statement to execute if `total` skips over a multiple of 4?

EDIT: say `foo = [4,5]`, then `total` takes the values `0`, `4`, and `9`. I want the print statement to execute twice, once for `4`, which it does, and once for `8`, which `total` "skips over" when it jumps from 4 to 9.

Comment: I'm confused. That's exactly what this code does.

Comment: When `total` is a multiple of `4` then you are printing `passed multiple of 4`. So, your code is working well. But What do you want ? Explain details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the print statement to execute twice, once for 4, which it does, and once for 8, which total "skips over" when it jumps from 4 to 9.

So basically, you do not want to check the modulus, but just whether the total passed a multiple of four.

Something like this:

```
def bar(lst):
    total = 0
    # keep track of the numbers we need to “pass” to print the notice; the first one is 4
    passed = 4

    for i in lst:
        total += i

        # when the total passed the number
        while total >= passed:
            # print the notice
            print('passed multiple of 4, total is {0}'.format(total))
            # and skip to the next number
            passed += 4
```

```
>>> bar([4, 5])
passed multiple of 4, total is 4
passed multiple of 4, total is 9
>>> bar([1, 3, 4])
passed multiple of 4, total is 4
passed multiple of 4, total is 8
>>> bar([1, 12])
passed multiple of 4, total is 13
passed multiple of 4, total is 13
passed multiple of 4, total is 13
```